# SQL Developer - Auto Formatting option

Tags: formatting, format, oracle-sqldeveloper

As you know, the shortcut for auto formatting the code written in Oracle SQL Developer is [Ctrl] + [F7], by default. My question is how I can edit the style of formatting of the code and especially if I can export this formatting, so that it can be applied to another computer? Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

From the Tools menu (or on OS X, the SQL Developer menu) go to Preferences. In versions up to 4.1.5, in the preference pane expand the Database section, and then the SQL Formatter section.

[image]

The top level lets you import and export settings, and the Oracle Formatting section lets you choose how you want your code to be formatted.

[image]

You can have multiple profiles with their own specific formatting if that's useful to you - maybe if you work on projects with different coding/style standards.

---

As @thatjeffsmith mentioned in a comment, since 4.2.0 this has moved to Preferences->Code Editor->Format->Advanced Format:

[image]

There is a section on this [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer/18.2/rptug/sql-developer-concepts-usage.html#GUID-9421DA6E-A48A-427B-88C9-4414D83EC9D1).

Comment: Since Alex answered this question, we moved the Formatter preferences from Database to be under Code Editor. The process/solution remains the same though.

Answer (score 2):

**Go to:**

```
Tools --> Preferences --> Database --> SQL Formatter --> Import/Export
```

Comment: @K.H. You should mark it as answered, would help others too!