# Can DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL procedure correct poor indentation?

Tags: oracle, schema

Here's the command to get the DDL or the procedure and make it pretty:

```
EXEC DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM , 'PRETTY' , TRUE);
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE', UPPER('LOOPPROC'), 'MYSCHEMA') FROM DUAL;
```

This is the output which is exactly like the input and the same as if PRETTY was set to FALSE above.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "MYLANID"."LOOPPROC" (inval NUMBER) 

IS

  tmpvar   NUMBER;
  tmpvar2   NUMBER;
  total     NUMBER;

BEGIN

  tmpvar := 0;
  tmpvar2 := 0;
  total := 0;

  FOR lcv IN 1 .. inval

  LOOP

      total := 2 * total + 1 - tmpvar2;
      tmpvar2 := tmpvar;
      tmpvar := total;

  END LOOP;

  IF inval = 1 THEN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('IN IF TRUE branch, inval = ' || inval);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('IN IF TRUE branch, inval is still = ' || inval);
  ELSE
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('IN ELSE, inval = ' || inval);
  END IF;
   

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('TOTAL IS: ' || total);

END loopproc;
```

Note how the IF - THE - ELSE clause is indented like the Snake River.

Is there a way to get the procedure to indent more conventionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’m also open to open source that can be called from .net. I’m considering as a last resort to use Selenium to take advantage of free web sites that do sql formatting but only as a last resort.

Idea: SQL Developer has already  built-in [formatting capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35575367/5070879) and allow to set multiple options.

Then using: [Command-Line Interface for SQL Developer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer/20.2/rptug/sql-developer-concepts-usage.html#GUID-6F4050CA-8ECC-4FC1-B5D9-CA8684391CB7):

> For certain operations, you can invoke SQL Developer from the command line as an alternative to the graphical user interface. To use the command-line interface, go to the sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin folder or sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin directory under the location where you installed SQL Developer, and enter sdcli.
>
> ```
> C:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin>sdcli
> ```
>
> Available features:
>
> **format: Format Task**

Invocation:

```
 sdcli format input=<here goes file>
```

I could imagine building following batch script/pipeline:

1. get object definition from Oracle
2. save it as file
3. use `sdcli format`
4. read the file content back

Comment: Lukasz, This looks like this works and will suit my purposes. I suspect that it may be slower than having the database do the format, I'm a bit disappointed (in Oracle) that  the PRETTY option didn't seem to work but I am quite leased that you pointed out this functionality. Thank you, sir!

Comment: While it works, it's very very slow. It takes about 20 seconds to format a 1200 line package.

Comment: @Chad 20s for a file is quite a bit especially if it has to be part of CI pipeline. I guess it is because of overhead to start SQL Developer. Maybe it would be faster by performing all files at once by providing `input=folder` or by two folders `input=folder1 output=folder2`

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, I was planning on trying the same thing but when IU saw your post, gave it a try. The performance was pretty good for a large number of files. The problem is that i developer a UI that allowed a user query a db object, get the DDL for every test and prod env (there's about 7 envs)  and then format and compare the DDL. Of the 7 envs. getting the DDL is super fast but waiting 20 seconds for SQL Discover to start up to do it's job is pretty slow for a UI transaction that is immediate if no formatting is required. (I get the DDL for all envs on seperate threads)